# Link button with video time

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to show a button only when the user reaches at a certain time of video, like button would appear only when the user has seen 20 minutes of video. Have no idea about it, would really appreciate inputs. Thanks

Comment: Please read "[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".  Then edit your answer,  thanks.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question, or is this just a thinly-veiled "do it all for me because I can't be bothered to find out how"?

Comment: Thanks Xero, I really apologize but actually I did research on this for two hours before asking question, but was bot able to find helping things. Would really appreciate if you can guide me even to a helping link for research. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well IF the video is playing through html5 (a video tag) NOT EMBEDDED the following code is one route you could take.

```
// the video element
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
// add an event listener for 'timeupdate' 
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    // 20 mins in seconds
    if ( this.currentTime == 1200) {
    // code to add the button here...
    }
}, false);
```

You should really check out [html5 audio/video api](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Comment: Thanks so very much for this great help. However, is there any chance with embeded videos too? I checked out youtube's video controls list and could not find any such trigger there.

Comment: Not a problem glad this helps. As for embedded videos, i am unfamiliar with youtubes api, but depending on the browser youtube videos will be played through flash or html5. Even if the video happens to be using the html5 api, because it is in an iframe with same-orgin policy you will not be able to user JavaScript on the frame document.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to know how to make a button appear or how to check the the current time of a video clip.

I'm hoping it's the former. To check the time of video playback you can call the currentTime property of your video using javascript, as such:

```
// set your video element to a variable
var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

// get the current playback time of the video (returned in seconds) and set to variable
current_playback_time = video.currentTime;
```